# prevent v-autocomplete from syncing search upon selecting option

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i'm trying to call api and show options upon an input.
Here is my v-autocomplete code.

```
<v-autocomplete
            v-model="filter.search"
            :items="entries"
            :loading="loading"
            :search-input.sync="search"
            hide-selected
            item-text="name"
            item-value="id"
            label="顧客・現場名"
            solo
            dense
            hide-details
            no-data-text="データがありません"
></v-autocomplete>
```

data attribute

```
 data() {
    return {
      filter: {
        year: this.getCurrentYear(),
        month: this.getCurrentMonth(),
        search: null,
      },
      search: null,
      entries: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };

  },
```

watcher

```
 watch: {
    filter: {
      handler() {
        this.getDataFromApi();
      },
      deep: true,
    },
    search(val) {
      if (this.isLoading) return;
    
      this.isLoading = true;
      let params = {};
      params.search = val;
    
      axios
        .get("/user/worktimes/get-sites", {
          params: {
            keyword: val,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.count = res.data.data.sites.length;
          this.entries = res.data.data.sites;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
        .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false));
    },

  },
```

and this is the data from the api if typing 'test'

```
{
    "sites": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "test /未登録案件"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "test blank /未登録案件"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "testing /未登録案件"
        },
        {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "test /asd"
        }
    ]
}
```

**issue**

this.search = 'test' while searching, but upon selecting an option from the dropdown,  it changes to the name attribute of selected option (for example: this.search will become 'test /未登録案件'), hence watcher get triggered , and calling api again.
Is it possible to not call api again or just not affecting the previous value of search attribute upon selection?

[image]

i'm sorry if it sounds silly, appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Try to look at [this example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#asynchronous-items).  In `search` watcher there is a condition `val && val !== this.select` which in your case should be `val && val !== this.filter.search.name`.

Also use `return-object` attribute on `<v-autocomplete>` to ensure you get whole object in `this.filter.search`, not just an id.

<strike>I am not able to reproduce your exact case, but I see you are watching both `this.search` and `this.filter.search` properties. You could try to refactor `filter` watcher not to watch for changes triggered solely on `filter.search` property.</strike>

Comment: filter.search is for getting the data in the page based on the option selected from the v-autocomplete, whereas this.search is for finding the option to show in the dropdown. 
i've edited the question with an image

Comment: thanks, but that's not working , this.filter.data is null until when we select an option, and on selecting the option, it gets the id of the option

Comment: @codeninja I presume you mean `this.filter.search` (instead of `this.filter.data`). Have you tried using `return-object` prop? This should give you the whole selected object data in `this.filter.search`. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props-return-object

Comment: ah yes! it was search, my mistake, but yes, i tried return-object, but changed that after many tries, and it also help me from formatting the ```filter.search```  attribute to get the id  while calling api

Comment: i mean, it was not working even with return-object,